# apply styles to all tables except one

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like some styles not to be applied to a table when the screen is too small.

The problem is that these styles are applied to table or tr or td etc.

Is there a way to point to all tables except this one? Maybe with some specific id?
What I don't want is to have to introduce the css properties myself, I just want them not to be applied to that specific table.

Thank you very much

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0px;
}   
td,
th {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Job Title</th> 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Matman</td>
      <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Andor</td>
      <td>Nagy</td>
      <td>Designer</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tamas</td>
      <td>Biro</td>
      <td>Game Tester</td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `:not(.tableclass)`?

Comment: I tried to use this but if not work.

Comment: Can you please make a [Minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then ?

Comment: I put the code of the table and the css. I use dataTables.

Comment: `thead:not(.special)` is not correct. You're trying to hide the table aren't you? Then why are you selecting the `thead` and not the table?

Comment: When not this table I want to hide the header. I don't want to hide it in this table

Comment: Well that's not what your post says but `:not(.special) thead` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:not` selector.

```css
div:not(.main){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div>A</div>
<div class="main">B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

Here is an example with 3 table and one thead shown :

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table:not(.main) thead {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="main">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>B</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also apply a class to the thead if you prefer and use `thead:not(.main)`