# Apply CSS to all but a few components

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a Qt5 project which uses QSS https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html, to customize its ui components. It customizes QComboBox across the entire project with something like

```
QComboBox {
    color: red;
}
```

I understand that it could be more selective by doing

```
MyClass QComboBox {
    color: red;
}
```

Now I would like to disable QSS for a few QComboBox, one approach to achieve that would be to apply the above idea. However I'll have to find out all the classes with QComboBox.

Is there a way to specify the classes to which I don't want QSS customization? Or the specific QComboBox to ignore?

Comment: You can check [:not() selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72216421/17684809) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:not))

Comment: Looks like is not available, https://forum.qt.io/topic/86918/in-qss-is-there-a-not-selector

Comment: Maybe then something like `QComboBox{border:1px solid black;}` and `QComboBox.special{border:none;}` for example

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using object name , [setObjectName(const QString &)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop)

```
QComboBox [objectName^="ComboBox1"] { color: red; }
```

or use [setAccessibleName(const QString &name)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#accessibleName-prop)

```
QComboBox [accessibleName="ComboBox1"] { color: red; }
```